# How do I block certain websites which have XYZ in their URL?

Tags: python

I wanted to write some code which

- limits the usage of some websites such as Instagram
- completely blocks porn sites by blocking every site with words such as "porn" or "xxx" in the URL
- switches the computer off automatically at some times

It all works out, except for the blocking websites part. I tried to access the host file, and redirect as soon as there are some words in the URL, it still doesn't work.

I honestly dont know why I can still access the websites.

I added it as top priority to the task scheduler, with starting the computer as a trigger
Thanks in advance guys!!

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import re
import os
#imporitng every module i might need
problemwörter_url = ["porn","hub","xxx","xnxx","xhamster","xvideos","tnaflix","tube8","xtube","mvtube",]

seltenwörter_url = ["instagram","facebook","looksmax","vimeo","dailymotion","kisscartoon","lichess","outlook","gmail"]
mittagspause_start = dt(now.year, now.month,now.day, 18, 30)
mittagspause_ende = dt(now.year, now.month, now.day,20,30)
now = dt.now()
noon = dt(now.year, now.month, now.day, 12, 0)
evening = dt(now.year, now.month, now.day, 21, 30)
if now <= noon or now >= evening:
    print("Turning off computer")

listeseltenerwörter = []
listeproblemwörter = []

for wort in problemwörter_url:
    listeproblemwörter.append(r"www.(.*)"+wort+r"(.*)(.de|.com|.net|.sh|.nz|.org|.co|.uk|.me)")

for item in seltenwörter_url:
    listeseltenerwörter.append(r"www.(.*)"+item+r"(.*)(.de|.com|.net|.sh|.nz|.org|.co|.uk|.me)")
#creating a list of words I want to limit and stop in my url
host_path = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "My Ip adress"

def blockiere_website(Liste)
    with open(host_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in Liste:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    # mapping hostnames to your localhost IP address
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
#blocking certain sites
if not datetime.now() <= evening and if not datetime.now() >= noon:
    blockiere_website(listeseltenerwörter)
#blocking sites in this list sometimes
blockiere_website(listeproblemwörter)
#blocking sites on this list permanently
```

Comment: "completely blocks porn sites by blocking every site with words such as "porn" or "xxx" in the URL" It'll block the ones that use those strings, but there are many that don't.

Comment: yeah thats right, but for starters that would eliminate my usual weaknesses. Not even that works though, I can access every site

Comment: Oh, and you've blocked anything that includes the word "hub." I'm pretty sure that's not exclusive to porn sites.

Comment: yeah good point. I can always edit that part tho, do you have any idea as to why nothing is blocked?

Comment: It seems that `host_path` is missing `\hosts` at the end, is it a typo?

Comment: I'd first ask, is it more important to you to _write_ a firewall program or to _have_ a firewall program?

Comment: yes, thats a typo! thanks a lot @HernánAlarcón

Comment: somehow its still now working.... @TigerhawkT3 I feel like Im just pretty close now, so I kinda want to finish it. Also I can modify my own program, and unlike programs like"freedom" its free

Comment: Check the code that is supposed to update the file. It looks weird. You are importing `re`, but why are you not using it if it seems that you use regular expressions?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Honestly, someone else gave me the file update code and said it worked for him, i havent worked that much with the os module... I imported re for the regex in the lists of problematic words.... Do you have more knowledge on updating that file?